# Bootstrap responsive-embed strange behaviour

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap's responsive-embed to embed a YouTube video but for some reason it doesn't show on the page at all.  I know it's on the page as I am using a screenreader which reads it and I can play it and hear the sound but visually it doesn't show at all.
Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
<div class="embed-responsive">
    <iframe class="col-md-4 embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b2l9tqv0AHs"></iframe> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your video player isn't visible because Boostrap's default CSS sets `.embed-responsive` height to 0px.

```
// From Bootstrap 3.3.7
.embed-responsive {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

To display your video player, you'll need to set the height. Looking at [Bootstrap's `embed-responsive` documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed), they provide a few optional dimensions:

```
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class=" col-md-4 embed-responsive-item"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b2l9tqv0AHs"></iframe> 
</div>

<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class=" col-md-4 embed-responsive-item"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b2l9tqv0AHs"></iframe> 
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could set your own custom height with custom CSS:

```
.embed-responsive { height:100px; }
```

See [live JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oze2khzy/).

Comment: Thanks @Devon Bernard with 16by9 it showed up but not with 4by3

Answer (score 0):

It's always good checking some other CSS or SCSS dependent file. In my case one sintax error there broken the other pages.